# Multithreaded AES encryption RunWorkerCompleted event never gets called

Tags: c#, multithreading, encryption

I am trying to achieve multithreaded AES encryption using Backgroundworker to get the events done. First I read the buffer send it to doworker event. That writes the inbuffer to outbuffer encrypted after the thread is done it needs to write in the RunWorkerCompleted method but it never gets called.

However when I slowly debug using a messagebox, the function fires up! successfully giving me my encrypted file. I don't understand any of this I would appreciate if somebody could help me how to translate this to a threadpool? or maybe explain why it doesn't call runworkercomplete when it is done because it show me the messagebox in the doworker event but not in the runworkercomplete event???

```
static List<BackgroundWorker> listWorkers = new List<BackgroundWorker>();
static List<BackgroundWorker> listFreeWorkers = new List<BackgroundWorker>();
static FileStream fsIn;
static string file;
static byte[] key;
const int BLOCK_SIZE = 1000;
static FileStream outFile;

public static void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile, string sKey, String privateKey, ProgressBar progress)
{
    String fileName = inputFile;
    fileName = "\\" + fileName.Split('\\').Last();
    var progres = new Progress<int>(value => progress.Value = value);
    file = outputFile + fileName;

    fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);
    outFile = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create);

    key = new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(sKey);

    for (int t = 0; t < 4; t++)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        listWorkers.Add(worker);
        listFreeWorkers.Add(worker);
    }


    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(inputFile);
    double numBlocks = Math.Ceiling(((double)fileInfo.Length) / BLOCK_SIZE);

    int ixCurrentBlock = 0;
    while (ixCurrentBlock < numBlocks)
    { 
        if (listFreeWorkers.Count > 0)
        {
            BackgroundWorker freeWorker = listFreeWorkers[0];
            listFreeWorkers.Remove(freeWorker);
            int bytes;

            if (ixCurrentBlock < numBlocks - 1)
            {

                byte[] buffer = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
                bytes = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
                freeWorker.RunWorkerAsync(Tuple.Create(ixCurrentBlock * BLOCK_SIZE, buffer));
            }
            else  //special handling for last block
            {
                int size = (int)(fileInfo.Length - ixCurrentBlock * BLOCK_SIZE);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                bytes = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                freeWorker.RunWorkerAsync(Tuple.Create(0, buffer));
            }

            ixCurrentBlock++;

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    var hasAllThreadsFinished1 = (from worker in listWorkers
                                  where worker.IsBusy
                                  select worker).ToList().Count;

    while (hasAllThreadsFinished1 != 0)
    {
        hasAllThreadsFinished1 = (from worker in listWorkers
                                  where worker.IsBusy
                                  select worker).ToList().Count;

    }

    fsIn.Close();
    outFile.Close();
    byte[] hash = Hashing.HashFile(outputFile + fileName, privateKey);
    File.WriteAllBytes(outputFile + "\\Hashing.txt", hash);
}

private static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Tuple<int, byte[]> t = e.Argument as Tuple<int, byte[]>;

    //int blockIndex = (int)t.Item1;
    byte[] inBuffer = (byte[])t.Item2;
    byte[] outBuffer;

    MessageBox.Show("Started");

    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(outStream,
                          RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                          CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            // I want to write inbuffer non encrypted to outbuffer encrypted.
            cs.Write(inBuffer, 0, inBuffer.Length);

        }
        outBuffer = outStream.ToArray();

    }


    e.Result = Tuple.Create(0, outBuffer);
    MessageBox.Show("done function");

}

static Object pen = new Object();

private static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
    Tuple<int, byte[]> t = e.Result as Tuple<int, byte[]>;
    //int blockIndex = (int)t.Item1;
    byte[] buffer = (byte[])t.Item2;
    bool b = true;

    while (b)
    {
        lock (pen)
        {
            outFile.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            listFreeWorkers.Add((BackgroundWorker)sender);
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
            b = false;
        }

    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The error tends to be when 4 threads are running at the same time. They simply get stuck I tested using a messageBox here.

```
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(outStream,
                          RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                          CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            // I want to write inbuffer non encrypted to outbuffer encrypted.
            cs.Write(inBuffer, 0, inBuffer.Length);


        }
        outBuffer = outStream.ToArray();
        MessageBox.Show(outBuffer[0] + " done function");
```

Will give me the encrypt file. This makes no sense why can't my threads run the dowork method at the same time :(?

Comment: I would suggest you have a look at Tasks. They provide a superior way to manage this type of parallel work. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't specify a **Block cipher mode** for `RijndaelManaged()` you get the default **[CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29)**. In **CBC mode** each block encrypted / decrypted are made dependent of the previous block. This prevents encrypt and decrypt of the individual blocks to be done in parallel.

Comment: `RMCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;` doesn't fix the problem :( threads still can't run at the same time. @Ebbe M. Pedersen